# Debian auto-apt: 404 not found

Tags: debian, apt

I am currently trying to learn/use the `auto-apt` command in a Debian testing, but it seems to fail updating its database:

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing  main contrib non-free

> sudo auto-apt update 
Downloading http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/testing Contents-amd64.gz ...
2015-07-25 18:12:02 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Is there an option to specify, or is my `sources.list` faulty?

Comment: Neither, it looks like. auto-apt is just out of date. There used to be top-level "Contents" files in the repo for Debian releases up to squeeze, but jessie and stretch don't have them, they have one per section (main, contrib, etc.) instead. auto-apt doesn't seem to know that.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/923411/why-are-there-no-contents-arch-gz-file-for-debian-jessie

Answer (score 1):

You can simply changing your /etc/apt/sources.list file by adding following lines :

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing/main /
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing/contrib /
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing/non-free /
```

Enter `sudo auto-apt update` command and it's working.
After this, you can restore your original sources.list file until next time you will have to perform another auto-apt update